# How to restrict asssignment to TypeVar to Hashable?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to restrict `TypeVar` role to `Hashable`.
For example,

```py
def convert_to_set(x: List[T]) -> Set[T]:
    return set(x)
```

I want to indicate that `T` is subclass of `Hashable`, because all elements of set must be hashable.

One of the solution I thought is the following:

```py
TH = TypeVar("TH", Hashable, Hashable)
```

However, I think this is ugly.

What should I do?

Comment: Note that ``Hashable`` is not properly type checked to begin with: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1746

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution from https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds

```py
T = TypeVar(T, bound=Hashable)
```